# How to increase efficiency of function calls in nested loops [2 million calls]

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops, sys, function-call

For a cybersecurity class, I have to write a python program to iterate through a .txt file of usernames and a .txt file of passwords, checking every combination of usernames and passwords as arguments against a Login() function (imported from Login.py) until I find one correct combination.

While the usernames file (gang.txt) is 20 lines long, the passwords file (PwnedPWs100k.txt) is 100,000 lines long, and so I have to call the Login() function **2 million** times. This program will likely take >50 hours to run, and I'm sure that our professor wanted us to accomplish this in a faster way, I'm just not sure what else I can make more efficient.

- The login function takes no parameters, instead using command line arguments to take `<user> <password>` as inputs, so I'm using sys.argv to set the arguments for each combination
- Login() will return 1 when a combination is correct.
- I have to print the time at the beginning and end of the program
- I am to skip the usernames 'Adam' and 'Donald'

**my code so far**:

```
import Login
import datetime
import sys         


if __name__ == "__main__":

  now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()  #instructed to print time at beginning and end of run
  print(now)

  #transfer contents of .txt file in lists (instructed to skip users Adam and Donald)
  with open("gang") as gang:
    gang_names = [name.strip() for name in gang if name.strip() not in ('Adam', 'Donald')]

  with open("PwnedPWs100k") as pws:
    passwords = [pw.strip() for pw in pws]

  for name in gang_names:
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], name, 'string']     
    for password in passwords:
      sys.argv[2] = password
      if Login.Login():
        print("USER: " + name + " PASSWORD: " + password)
        break

  now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  print(now)
```

**Any ideas on how to more efficiently do this?**

Comment: Are the passwords all unique? If not, you could feed it into a `set()` to reduce the amount that you'd have to iterate through. If you don't know, probably worth doing still since it won't add too much to the overall runtime comparatively. Other than that, does each `username` have one `password`, and do you need to have the printed output in a particular order. As @Pingu mentioned you can consider multiprocessing to help scale down your time. You don't have much options to reduce the time complexity itself though.

Comment: side note: I think it should be `sys.argv[1] = password`. I would propose multi-threading as well. If you have information on the password criteria that the login function requires I would suggest to filter your PWs to meet those requirements.

Comment: Alternatively, as its cyber security class: How about hacking the Login function? ;-)

Comment: @LukasHestermeyer We don't know for sure but if *Login()* is CPU-intensive then multithreading may not be a good idea

Comment: Have you considered multiprocessing (which is typically ideal for something that is [probably] CPU-intensive)? Can you share the code for Login ?

Comment: Technically the Login function is imported from an encrypted Login.pyc file that I am not allowed to change. All the passwords in the file are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a multiprocessing implementation of your code. If you want to use multithreading just import ThreadPoolExecutor and replace the ProcessPoolExecutor with that. No other changes would be needed.

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import Login
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process(name):
    if name not in {'Adam', 'Donald'}:
        with open('PwnedPWs100k') as pwf:
            for password in map(str.strip, pwf):
                sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], name, password]
                if Login.Login():
                    return f'USER: {name} PASSWORD: {password}'

def main():
    with open('gang') as gang:
        with Pool() as pool:
            for result in pool.imap_unordered(process, map(str.strip, gang)):
                if result:
                    pool.terminate()
                    print(result)
                    break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(datetime.utcnow())
    main()
    print(datetime.utcnow())
```

Each subprocess deals with just one name (from 'gang').